# Verifying if data exists in my Table using TClientDataSet in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I am trying to verify if [specific] data exists in my table using TClientDataSet. I

Is there a way that I can do this in TClientDataSet?

I am avoiding to use query for some reason here.

Comment: Your q isn't really clear enough.  When you say "if data exists", do you mean you want to know whether a specific records in in the table, or just whether it contains any data at all, regardless of what it is?  Look up  `TClietDataSet.Locate` function in the Online Help.

Comment: Or perhaps if you want to find out if data exists in the table or not, you can use `IsEmpty`. BTW it's very possible to use a query as a data source for a client data set. That's to say, I find that part unclear too.

Comment: @MartynA I edited my question 'specific'.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Sorry if its not so clear but what I am looking is specific data. I got it already from the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows how to check whether a TClientDataSet contains any data and how to find whether it contains a record with a field having a specific value (or a record containg a combination of values in multiple fields)

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  Field : TField;
  S : String;
begin

  //  Create 2 fields in the CDS

  Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'ID';
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  Field := TStringField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'Name';
  Field.Size := 40;
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  //  Next, set up the CDS; it will be empty initially
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;

  if CDS1.IsEmpty then
    ShowMessage('Is empty - no data')
  else
    ShowMessage('Something went wrong');

  CDS1.IndexFieldNames := 'Name;ID';
  CDS1.InsertRecord([1, 'One']);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([2, 'Two']);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([3, 'Three']);

  ShowMessage('DataSet now contains ' + IntToStr(CDS1.RecordCount) + ' records');

  S := 'Two';
  if CDS1.Locate('Name', S, []) then
    ShowMessage('Found record with Name = ' + S)
  else
    ShowMessage('Failed to find record with Name = ' + S);

  //  Following shows how to use Locate on more than one field
  //  Note: to use VarArrayOf, you need Variants in your uses list
  if CDS1.Locate('ID;Name', VarArrayOf([1, 'one']), [loCaseInsensitive])  then
    ShowMessage('Found record by multiple criteria');
end;
```

Note that setting the IndexFieldNames to 'Name;ID' is to speed up the Locate operation if there are a lot of records.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use FindKey, which is faster than Locate.
You must have an index active for the column you want to verify.
For example:

```
CDS1.IndexFieldNames := 'Name;ID';
if CDS1.FindKey(['one',1]) then DoSomething;
```

Locate does not require an index, but for FindKey index is necessary and it takes time to create it. Therefore, sometimes the profit at the time of execution of FindKey is lost due to the time the index was created.